# Rails: Adding routes to singleton resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

So, if I have a singleton route...

```
resource :shared
```

... and I want to have custom action names instead of the standard CRUD names, do I still do...

```
resource :shared do
  collection do
    get 'foo'
    get 'bar'
    match 'baz'
  end
end
```

... or can I go without the "collection" block and pass those routes directly to the singleton?

In this case I don't want any of the standard CRUD routes either...

Is there a simpler, cleaner way to setup routes to only the specific ajax related actions for my shared resources? I'm using this controller very sparsely, mostly it exists so that the `shared` view folder can serve things like my footer and my menus...

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `match`

Say for example you have a controller called `FooController` and a method called `bar` you could do the following:

`match "/foo/bar/" => "foo#bar", :as => "foo_bar"`

That would match any request, be it GET or POST, to your `FooController` with method `bar`

Replace `match` with `post` or `get` if you only want one specific http verb.

Comment: Controllers' names should always be plural, so "FoosController" rather than "FooController", and "foos#bar" rather than "foo#bar".

Answer (score 0):

The resource code looks like this:

```
collection do
  post :create
end if parent_resource.actions.include?(:create)

new do
  get :new
end if parent_resource.actions.include?(:new)

member do
  get    :edit if parent_resource.actions.include?(:edit)
  get    :show if parent_resource.actions.include?(:show)
  put    :update if parent_resource.actions.include?(:update)
  delete :destroy if parent_resource.actions.include?(:destroy)
end
```

So you can basically do the same thing, but with your own names.